# Access Database is producing the same results for what is supposed to be a random number query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have made a small quiz for some students using access. I split the database. There are 12 terminals from which students will take the quiz. I put the front end on each of these terminals and the backend is stored on the network drive which is connected to all the terminals. Now, the quiz is supposed to pick 20 random multiple choice questions. The query is fine. It's just that when students start their own database session from their own terminals, they all end up getting the same random questions. This defeats the purpose of giving a quiz as they can all look over their shoulders. I don't know why this is happening. It seems to me that the database has saved the results of the random questions query and is not executing the query each time like it is supposed to. Also, for some reason, the database is very very slow now. Seems to me that it is pulling things out of memory. What do i do?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT TOP 20 MCQuestionsT.QuestionID, MCQuestionsT.QuestionText, MCQuestionsT.QuestionImage, MCQuestionsT.ChoiceA, MCQuestionsT.ChoiceB, MCQuestionsT.ChoiceC, MCQuestionsT.ChoiceD, MCQuestionsT.ChoiceE
FROM MCQuestionsT
WHERE (((MCQuestionsT.CourseCode)="2323"))
ORDER BY Rnd(MCQuestionsT.QuestionID);
```

Comment: Do you have your random question code to show us?

Comment: How is your application picking the 20 random questions?  Can you post any code to demonstrate what's actually happening?

Also, as a general rule, Access databases slow down when in use by multiple users...if you're wanting something quicker think about using SQL server or another server-based database technology.

Comment: That's the code. The code works all the time picking random questions from the MCQuestions table. But now when students run their front end form, right before the form that contains the 20 questions, the query seems to give the same 20 questions on every single terminal. I

Comment: I think that somehow access database is not executing the query for every user as I thought it would.

Comment: I think the problem is with having the database connections from the individual front ends to the backend not share the data or something like that. The problem is not with the query itself.

Comment: When you use a seed value with Rnd you are always going to get the same result for that specific seed value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to seed further the random generator:

```
SELECT TOP 20 
    MCQuestionsT.QuestionID, MCQuestionsT.QuestionText, MCQuestionsT.QuestionImage, MCQuestionsT.ChoiceA, MCQuestionsT.ChoiceB, MCQuestionsT.ChoiceC, MCQuestionsT.ChoiceD, MCQuestionsT.ChoiceE
FROM 
    MCQuestionsT
WHERE 
    CourseCode="2323"
ORDER BY 
    Rnd(-Timer()*[QuestionID]);
```

Comment: This seems to work. But I don't know how. However, in one instance, produced the same quiz on two different terminals. I asked a colleague to take the quiz on both the terminals at the same time. He started the quiz as closely as possible in time on the two terminals. Is it possible, that he started it exactly at the same second for the random questions generator to generate the same quiz for both terminals?

Comment: Yes, it would be possible. Have in mind, that _Rnd_ in fact only returns a fixed series of pseudo-random values, then starts over. What _Randomize_ (and the peculiar expression above) does, is only to determine where in the sequence to start. This means that you could print out the values and - given a certain series of values - determine where in the sequence the values occur and then determine the next value. This is, of course, not random, thus the label pseudo-random. Obtaining true random numbers is an art by itself.